# Is it possible to resume file upload on server side in php? If yes, how ?

Tags: php, multipartform-data

at the time of file uploading suppose user's connection is lost then how can we handle this situation , user wants resume file upload instead of restart.

Comment: You'll need to use chunking. Take a look at this: http://www.resumablejs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, you can do it. Best you have to use any plugin or javascript
>   library, or you can do it using core php. divide your image in small
>   pieces(use any tool for this), upload that small pieces on server one
>   by one and get response from server after each successful upload. In
>   the middle if connection lost then we are sure we have uploaded 3
>   small piece on server (1 image = 5 small piece). Then after if we
>   connected again then 1st it check how many small images uploaded,
>   server give response 3 then remaining 2 small images will be upload on
>   server

Comment: It's ok, but suppose I have 10MB data to be upload. there is 5 pieces each of size 2MB and 1MB of first piece is uploaded and then suddenly connection is lost then how can I restart from (1024 * 1024 + 1). User don't want to reload any byte of data.                                             Thanks, Monty...

Comment: in that case either you have to make very small pieces or do it from beginning

Comment: Very small piece is not possible because data may be > 3GB. client side developers have some limits into multi threading (Android and IOS) when they are sending piece data from mobile.

Comment: i recommend you to use node.js